# How do I convert from UTF8 symbols back to ISO-8859-1?

Tags: php, utf-8, iso-8859-1, utf8-decode

After getting data from a database as UTF8 my text looks like this (example):

> Str\u00f8msveien

This should be

> Strømsveien

How do I get my ISO-8859-1 symbols back?

I've tried `mb_convert_encoding($jsonstring, "iso-8859-1", "UTF8");` and `utf8_decode($jsonstring);` none of which worked.

Comment: I see. That's... embarrassing. Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: You might have wanted to use the string from within PHP. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first string is *not* UTF-8 encoded, but contains JavaScript escapes. You don't need to convert those, JavaScript can cope with them.